# Template Typed Method GTesting

Tags: c++, templates, googletest

This is what I have:

```
/* Can't change 'base' struct. */
struct base {
  public:
    template<typename T>
    void printVal() {
      std::cout << T::x << std::endl;
    }
};

struct testFixture
  : public base
  , public ::testing::Test {
  using base::printVal;
};

TEST_F(testFixture, testF) {
  printVal<A>();
  printVal<B>();
  printVal<C>();
}
```

Which works fine. But, I want to use typed tests so the code looks something more like this:

```
/* Same base class as above. */
struct testFixture
  : public base
  , public ::testing::Test {
  using base::printVal;
};

typedef ::testing::Types<A, B, C> MyTypes;
TYPED_TEST_CASE(testFixture, MyTypes);

TYPED_TEST(testFixture, typedTest) { 
  printVal<TypeParam>();
}
```

Of course, since 'testFixture' is not a templated struct/class, this will not work, and I get this error:

```
test2.cpp:31:12: error: unknown template name 'testFixture'
TYPED_TEST(testFixture, typedTest) {
```

Is there a way I can get this type of functionality using googletest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.

'templatize' the fixture:

```
template <typename T>
struct testFixture
  : public base
  , public ::testing::Test {
  using base::printVal;
  void printVal() {
    base::printVal<T>();
  }
};
```

And then proceed as normal:

```
typedef ::testing::Types<A, B, C> MyTypes;
TYPED_TEST_CASE(testFixture, MyTypes);

TYPED_TEST(testFixture, typedTest) {
  this->template printVal<TypeParam>();
}
```